# Meaning and conservation of integrals of momentum with respect to velocity

Tags: momentum, energy-conservation, conservation-laws, integration

Mass is usually conserved, momentum is usually conserved, energy is usually conserved (assuming there is not net force on the system). This gives rise to the natural question:
Is $\frac{1}{6} m v^3$ conserved?
and more generally:
Is $\frac{1}{n!} m v^n$ conserved?
Furthermore, what is the meaning behind these higher order integrals with respect to velocity. The units of $\frac{1}{6} m v^3$ are $kg\,m^3 s^{-3}$ so it seems as though it could be related to power times distance. Is there a name for this quantity and a good way to think about it?

Comment: It's a good guess, but no. In a one dimensional two-object elastic collision, the result is already fully determined by momentum and energy conservation. Adding another independent conservation law would make it impossible for anything to happen.

Comment: Can you explain why a bit more please? It looks too mathematically beautiful to be wrong, in my opinion. Why would the conservation suddenly choose to stop at $v^3$?

Comment: It's not so much that it chooses to stop, it's that the first three cases are true for completely different reasons. There's not a common structure there.

Comment: Oh. Why are they true and $v^3$ isn't?

Comment: I added a full answer. Also, I'd really caution you against thinking that things have to be true because of 'mathematical beauty', that's totally antithetical to what physics is!

Comment: Dirac would disagree....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern doesn't continue for higher powers of $v$, and we shouldn't expect it to continue, because they hold for completely different reasons.

- The total mass (which here I'm considering to be the sum of the rest masses of the particles) is conserved only in the nonrelativistic limit, where energies are small compared to $mc^2$.
- The total momentum is conserved by spatial translational symmetry.
- The total energy is conserved by time translational symmetry.

There are no more symmetries in a generic system (besides rotations and (Galilean) boosts, which give something different), so we don't expect $\sum mv^3$ to be conserved.

In the relativistic case, things break down even further. Neither $\sum m$ nor $\sum mv^2$ are conserved; instead, they combine into $\sum \gamma m$, which is the total relativistic energy. The quantity $\sum mv$ isn't conserved either and has to be replaced with $\sum \gamma m v$. So the pattern is a lot weaker than it looks at first glance.